# How do I get some variable from another class in Java?

Tags: java

I am "playing around" with Java, watching tutorials and trying to get the hang of it. For this question, I'm trying to figure out how I can take a variable from another class and use it in my main one, without making the initial variable public. Here is the code:

I am trying to get `int x` equal to 5 (as seen in the `setNum()` method), but when it prints it gives me 0.

Main Class:

```
package getVarTest;

public class Main { 
    public static void main (String[]args){
        Vars varsObject = new Vars();
        int x = varsObject.getNum();
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Variable Class:

```
package getVarTest;

    public class Vars {
        private int num;
            public void setNum(int x){
                this.num = 5;
            }
            public int getNum(){
                return num;
            }
    }
```

So, as you can see I am trying to take the `private int num` and make the `int x` in the main class equal to it.

Comment: Your code works fine.  What is your question?

Comment: Sorry let me fix my question

Comment: To get an answer, you need to ask a question.

Comment: What happens when you run it? What's your question?
(It might help if your test ran setNum() before it called getNum()... otherwise you're going to get num's initial value.)

Comment: You are getting a variable from another class.

Comment: Thanks for the responses and please read the new edit

Comment: You **do not call** `setNum()`.

Comment: x is 0 because you are not actually setting anything!

Comment: Please stop changing your question. It's annoying. You _can_ edit the question to add clarifications, but if you edit the code you might change the nature of your question. In this particular case, you edited your question to add an answer. You should have done that by posting an answer, not by editing the question!

Comment: There is no issue with the proposed code

Comment: The issue was resolved when I selected the best answer 17 hours ago and I now have it figured out. I removed the edited in answer, so I'm not really sure what you're upset about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do **NOT** do that! `setNum(num);//fix- until someone fixes your setter. Your getter should not call your setter with the uninitialized value of`num`(e.g.`0`).

I suggest making a few small changes -

```
public static class Vars {
  private int num = 5; // Default to 5.

  public void setNum(int x) {
    this.num = x; // actually "set" the value.
  }

  public int getNum() {
    return num;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

> I am trying to get int x equal to 5 (as seen in the setNum() method) but when it prints it gives me 0.

To run the code in `setNum` you have to call it.  If you don't call it, the default value is `0`.

Answer (score 3):

You never call `varsObject.setNum();`

Answer (score 1):

If the variable is public you can get it just by saying `packageName.ClassName.variableName`, but if it is private you will have to make a getter method inside the class that the variable is in. It will look something like this:

```
public int getVariableName() {
    return variableName;
}
```

Then just call that method wherever you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is perfect: the field is private and it has a getter. This is the normal way to access a field.
If you need a direct access to an object field, use reflection. Using reflection to get a field's value is a hack and should be used in extreme cases such as using a library whose code you cannot change.

Answer (score 0):

The code that you have is correct. To get a variable from another class you need to create an instance of the class if the variable is not static, and just call the explicit method to get access to that variable. If you put get and set method like the above is the same of declaring that variable public.

Put the method setNum private and inside the getNum assign the value that you want, you will have "get" access to the variable in that case